# Check if string contains pattern for regular expression

Tags: python

In my python function I want to take some action if supplied parameter contains a string representing a regex (ex-`r'^\D{2}$'`). How can I check if that string has regex pattern like this?

Comment: So, in other words, you have a string, and want to know if it can be used as a regex pattern?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps attempt to compile the string:

```
def is_regex(s):
    try:
       re.compile(s)
       return True
    except:
       return False
```

Comment: it doesnt throw exception for something like this : re.compile('Hello World')

Comment: True, but that not an error as `re.compile('Hello World').match('Hello World').group(0) == 'Hello World'`.

Comment: If you don't want `'Hello World'` to be considered valid, you would need to define what subset of regexes are to be accepted. As clearly that remark means that you don't want the entire set of regexes.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `re` module.

```
import re

s = <some string>
p = <regex pattern>
if re.search(p, s):
    # do something
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But there could be too many regex patterns

Comment: in you code, I have to know it beforehand that which patterns I have to check the string against

Comment: you want to search for dynamic patterns?

Comment: no problem, I got to know about search method of re

Answer (score 1):

There is a tricky way to do it. You can try to match the pattern with itself as a string and if it returns None you can consider it as regexp.

```
import re

def is_regex_pattern(pattern: str) -> bool:
    """Returns False if the pattern is normal string"""
    return not re.match(pattern, pattern)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
import re
pattern=r'^\D{2}$'
string="Your String here"


import re

try:
    re.compile(pattern)
    is_valid = True
except re.error:
    is_valid = False

if is_valid:
    matchObj = re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)
    if matchObj :
        #do something
else:
    #do something
```

Comment: The questions says "contains a string representing a regex". search should be used, not match.

Comment: I think the OP is receiving the string `'^\D{2}$'` from an outside source, and wants to determine if it can be used as a regex at all. Rather than return `True` for valid pattern strings and `False` otherwise, your code simply crashes for bad patterns.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import re

match_regex = re.search(r'^\D{2}$','somestring').group()

# do something with your matched string
```